# Angular dir-pagination

Tags: angularjs, pagination

If I put a `max-size` on this [working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/ln8RppPUvlb6zVbYN0bI?p=preview) I cant generate the next page of current page. For example when I click the 3 the next page is not generated

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li dir-paginate="item in collection | filter:q | itemsPerPage: pageSize" current-page="currentPage">{{ item }}</li>
</ul>

  <dir-pagination-controls max-size='5' on-page-change="pageChangeHandler(newPageNumber)"></dir-pagination-controls>
```

SCRIPT

```
$scope.currentPage = 1;
  $scope.pageChangeHandler = function(num) {
        $scope.currentPage = num;
    };
  $scope.pageSize = 10;
  $scope.collection = [];

  for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    $scope.collection.push('item ' + i);
  }
```

Library

```
dirPagination.js
```

Update

And it is possible to hide also the first and last page? In my plnkr its 1 and 20.

Comment: The "working example" you shared, seems to be working fine.

Comment: @Sajal when you click to number 3 the number 4 will not show

Comment: Looks like, anything <= 5 for the `max-size` attribute has this bug or maybe a default feature.. anything > 5 works fine.

Comment: @Sajal I see put how can I hide the first and last page? if the current page is in the middle?

Comment: I updated the plnkr.

Comment: This is the official documentation for [dir-paginate](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination#dir-pagination-controls), currently, there is no option to show/hide first and last page as they are required to iterate. If you need to do it anyhow, you would have to alter the library code as per your convenience.

Comment: @Sajal I see so nothing I can do